# Как можно приравнять массивы по индексам

Tags: java, массивы

Есть 2 массива
`private String[] place = {"Сочи","Казань","Геленджик","Анапа"}; private int[] poot = {12000,31000,32000,12345};`
Как можно приравнять массивы по индексу?
Мне нужно приравнять введенное значение пользователем например 'Сочи' и цену '12000'

Comment: наверно, вам надо бы объяснить, какой именно смысл вы вкладываете в глагол «приравнять». напишите это, пожалуйста, прямо в тексте вопроса, нажав [edit].

Comment: действительно, не совсем понятно что Вы имели ввиду под "приравнять". Можно перебрать в цикле через i счетчик, либо создать ассоциативный массив `HashMap(key, value)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да возьмите и переберите всё в цикле:

```
for (int i = 0; i < place.length && i < poot.length; ++i) {
    // TODO какие-либо действия с place[i] и poot[i]
}
```

Если вы ждёте какую то одну феноменальную строчку, которая всё это соединит, то явно не в Java её ждать нужно. Да даже если найдете, то в любом случае это нужно приводить к общему знаменателю — классу `Object` и выйдет только хуже (если вы хотели объединить эти массивы)